# Running (X) Xfce4 in Debian chroot

Tags: x11, chroot

I was trying to start Xfce4 in a chroot.

The problem is that Xfce4 starts, shows default the UI but the USB keyboard and mouse are not working.

My chroot script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount --bind /dev /srv/nboot_i386/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /srv/nboot_i386/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /srv/nboot_i386/proc
mount --bind /sys /srv/nboot_i386/sys
mount --bind /tmp /srv/nboot_i386/tmp
chroot /srv/nboot_i386/ /bin/bash
umount /srv/nboot_i386/dev
umount /srv/nboot_i386/dev/pts
umount /srv/nboot_i386/proc
umount /srv/nboot_i386/sys
umount /srv/nboot_i386/tmp
```

When I copy the chroot filesystem onto a separate HDD, and install a bootloader to make it boot, everything works fine.

I also tried to run KDE4 the same way and the keyboard and mouse weren't working, so it seems the chrooted X server is causing trouble. I've studied the X server log, but haven't found anything suspicious.

I'am using Virtualbox, but the problem is same on the real PC.

What I do: debootstrap, install Xfce4 in chroot, run Xfce4. I've tested i386/amd64 Wheezy/Jessie

What magic am I missing?

I've found the answer at last - `/run/udev` should be binded also.

I think this info may be helpfull.

Comment: Rather than add your answer in your question, add it as an answer in its own right and accept it.

Comment: can't answer my own question. no UI for that )

Comment: When you scroll to the bottom, there's a button "Answer Your Question". Click the button, confirm "Yes, I want to post an answer", and you're ready to go.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche there wasnt in 2013 though